# weird pthread_mutex_t behavior

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Consider the next piece of code -

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int sharedIndex = 10;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void* foo(void* arg)
{
    while(sharedIndex >= 0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        cout << sharedIndex << endl;
        sharedIndex--;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main() {

    pthread_t p1;
    pthread_t p2;
    pthread_t p3;

    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, foo, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p2, NULL, foo, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p3, NULL, foo, NULL);

    pthread_join(p1, NULL);
    pthread_join(p2, NULL);
    pthread_join(p3, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I simply created three `pthreads` and gave them all the same function `foo`, in hope that every thread, at its turn, will print and decrement the `sharedIndex`.

But this is the output -

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
-1
-2
```

- I don't understand why the process doesn't stop when `sharedIndex`
  reaches 0.
- `sharedIndex` is protected by a `mutex`. How come it's accessed after it became 0? Aren't the threads supposed to directly skip to `return NULL;`?

**EDIT**

In addition, it seems that only the first thread decrements the `sharedIndex`.
Why isn't every thread decrement the shared resource at it's turn? 
Here's the output after a fix -

```
Current thread: 140594495477504
10
Current thread: 140594495477504
9
Current thread: 140594495477504
8
Current thread: 140594495477504
7
Current thread: 140594495477504
6
Current thread: 140594495477504
5
Current thread: 140594495477504
4
Current thread: 140594495477504
3
Current thread: 140594495477504
2
Current thread: 140594495477504
1
Current thread: 140594495477504
0
Current thread: 140594495477504
Current thread: 140594478692096
Current thread: 140594487084800
```

I wish that all of the thread will decrement the shared source - Meaning, every contex switch, a different thread will access the resource and do its thing.

Comment: try calling `pthread_mutex_init` before creating threads and `pthread_mutex_destroy` at the very end of the program

Comment: Why don't you try fixing the undefined behaviour in your code and see if it helps?

Comment: I did change the code and it worked. But still - only a single threads decrement the resource

Comment: @AlexGoft That's the most efficient behavior. Switching threads takes time, so the implementation tries to let each thread run for at least a few milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you, David. Do you mean that between switching the first thread with the second, the first thread locks and unlocks the mutex multiple times - resulting in decrementing the resource till its 0?

Comment: Not "between switching the first thread with the second" but "before the second thread gets a chance to run". See the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program's behaviour is undefined.

You have not initialized the mutex. You need to either call `pthread_mutex_init` or statically initialize it:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

You read this variable outside the critical section:

```
while(sharedIndex >= 0)
```

That means you could read a garbage value while another thread is updating it. You should not read the shared variable until you have locked the mutex and have exclusive access to it.

**Edit:**

> it seems that only the first thread decrements the `sharedIndex`

That's because of the undefined behaviour. Fix the problems above and you should see other threads run.

With your current code the compiler is allowed to assume that the `sharedIndex` is never updated by other threads, so it doesn't bother re-reading it, but just lets the first thread run ten times, then the other two threads run once each.

> Meaning, every contex switch, a different thread will access the resource and do its thing.

There is no guarantee that pthread mutexes behave fairly. If you want to guarantee a round-robin behaviour where each thread runs in turn then you will need to impose that yourself, e.g. by having another shared variable (and maybe a condition variable) that says which thread's turn it is to run, and blocking the other threads until it is their turn.

Answer (score 3):

The threads will be hanging out on `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);` waiting to get the lock. Once a thread decrements to 0 and releases the lock, the next thread waiting at lock will then go about it's business (making the value -1), and same for the next thread (making the value -2).

You need to alter your logic on checking value and locking the mutex.

Answer (score 3):

```
int sharedIndex = 10;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void* foo(void* arg)
{
    while(sharedIndex >= 0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        cout << sharedIndex << endl;
        sharedIndex--;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

According to this code `sharedIndex` is the *shared resource* for all the threads.

Thus each access to it (both read and write) should be wrapped by mutex.
Otherwise assume the situation where all the threads sample `sharedIndex` simultaneously and its value is `1`.

All threads, then, enter the `while` loop and each one decreases `sharedIndex` by one leading it to `-2` at the end.

**EDIT**

Possible fix (as one of the possible options):

```
bool is_positive;
do
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    is_positive = (sharedIndex >= 0);
    if (is_positive)
    {
        cout << sharedIndex << endl;
        sharedIndex--;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}while(is_positive);
```

**EDIT2**

Note that you must initialize the mutex:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: Great answer until the last paragraph, which earned a downvote. `volatile` is not useful here, the compiler will never move accesses of the variable outside the mutex locks, (unless the compiler is totally broken) so it doesn't matter if it uses a register, as long as the result ends up in memory at the end of the critical section.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The compiler may (probably) move `sharedIndex` to `eax` at the beginning of the function and store it back to `sharedIndex` right before `return`. Maybe it won't do it but I don't know if any "law" can be applied here which will prevent the compiler from doing it. If the compiler will know the implementation of `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock`, it may get to the concution that nothing effects `sharedIndex` and `sharedIndex` doesn't effect these functions. So such optimization is possible.

Comment: If the compiler knows the implementation of `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` then it will know they contain the necessary memory synchronization to prevent exactly what you're worried about, so it won't get it wrong. If it doesn't know the implementation then it can't do that anyway, so it still won't get it wrong. Using `volatile` here is useless, and causees confusion. `volatile` is not useful for multithreaded programming in C and C++.

Comment: N.B. the compiler *can* use a register for the OP's code and never re-read the shared variable, because it has undefined behaviour. But if it's fixed to stop reading the variable outside the critical section then it can't do that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely after reading more about `volatile` in multithreaded C/C++ applications, I tend to agree with you. I removed the "suggestion" section.

Comment: Have an upvote, it's now an entirely great answer :) There are relevant links at http://cpp.isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/ but the site is temporarily unavailable